# JavaScript: How to get specific value from JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, model-view-controller

I have the following code in which I fetch data from the JSON file , I Store data in `$scope.users` variable, But I want to fetch only username value how can I do this?

**LoginCtrl.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('User').controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','$state', "SettingService","UserService", function($scope,$state, SettingService,UserService) {

$scope.users = [];

  UserService.getLoginInfo().then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data.data["username"];
  }, function(error){

  })

    var vm = this;

    vm.doLogin = function(){
        var username = document.forms["loginForm"]["email"].value;
var password = document.forms["loginForm"]["password"].value;
if(username == "admin@gmail.com" )
{
    if(password == "admin")
    {
        $state.go('app.home');
    }
}
    };
}]);
```

**User.json**

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "data": [
        { "id": 1, "username":"admin@gmail.com", "password":"admin"}


    ]
}
```

Comment: It should be `response.data.data[0]["username"]` as the inner `data` is an array

Comment: `response.data.data[0]["username"]`

Comment: thankyou so much @PankajParkar  :)

Comment: thanks @Edison :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get value for that JSON value as

```
response.data.data[0]["username"]
```

If you want to get all the usernames from the array, then you can do something like this:

```
var arr = response.data.map(function(a, b){
   return a.username;
});
```

`arr` will contain all the username details